# Vector of vector re-size

Tags: vector, julia

So I have two vector of vectors like:

> matchings_vec = Vector{Vector{Vector{Vector{Any}}}}(num_tilt1)
>
> Minfoall_vec = Vector{Vector{Vector{Vector{Vector{Vector{Float64}}}}}}(num_tilt1)

I defined it as:

```
matchings_vec = [Vector{Any}() for i in 1:num_tilt1]
Minfoall_vec = [Vector{Float64}() for i in 1:num_tilt1]
```

Then I am trying to resize the inner vectors like:

```
for tt = 1:num_tilt1
    t_tt = t[tt] #; t1 = t_tt; t2 = 1;
    if t_tt == 1
        num_rot1 = 1
    else
        num_rot1 = round(Int, num_rot_t2 * t_tt/2)
        if rem.(num_rot1, 2) == 1.0
            num_rot1 += 1
        end
        num_rot1 /= 2
    end
    num_rot1 = round(Int, num_rot1)
    #resize!(matchings_vec[tt], num_rot1)
    matchings_vec[tt] = Vector{Any}(num_rot1)
    #resize!(Minfoall_vec[tt], num_rot1)
    Minfoall_vec[tt] = Vector{Float64}(num_rot1)
    for rr = 1:num_rot1
        num_tilt2 = round(Int, num_tilt2)
        #resize!(matchings_vec[tt][rr], num_tilt2)
        matchings_vec[tt][rr] = Vector{Any}(num_tilt2)
        #resize!(Minfoall_vec[tt][rr], num_tilt2)
        Minfoall_vec[tt][rr] = Vector{Float64}(num_tilt2)
        for tt2 = 1:num_tilt2
            t_im2 = t[tt2]
            #t_im2_1 = t_im2; t_im2_2 = 1;
            if t_im2 == 1
                num_rot1_2 = 1
            else
                num_rot1_2 = round(Int, num_rot_t2 * t_im2/2)
                if rem.(num_rot1_2, 2) == 1.0
                    num_rot1_2 += 1
                end
                num_rot1_2 /= 2
            end
            num_rot1_2 = round(Int, num_rot1_2)
            #resize!(matchings_vec[tt][rr][tt2], num_rot1_2)
            matchings_vec[tt][rr][tt2] = Vector{Any}(num_rot1_2)
            #resize!(Minfoall_vec[tt][rr][tt2], num_rot1_2)
            Minfoall_vec[tt][rr][tt2] = Vector{Float64}(num_rot1_2)
        end
    end
end
```

I am getting this error:

> MethodError: Cannot `convert` an object of type Array{Float64,1} to an
> object of type Float64 This may have arisen from a call to the
> constructor Float64(...), since type constructors fall back to convert
> methods.
>
> Stacktrace:  [1] setindex!(::Array{Float64,1}, ::Array{Float64,1},
> ::Int64) at ./array.jl:578  [2] macro expansion at ./In[32]:22
> [inlined]  [3] anonymous at ./:?

Can you suggest what I am doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: What is `num_tilt2`? It seems to just appear out of nowhere in the example code you provide. I'm guessing it is of type `Float64` and so the error is caused by `Vector{Any}(num_tilt2)`, because Julia doesn't automatically convert scalar types to arrays. So `Vector{Any}(0.0)` will cause an error, but `Vector{Any}([0.0])` will not (although I'm not sure why you would specifically want a `Vector{Any}` when you could have a `Vector{Float64}`... it isn't clear to me what you're trying to do with this code)

Comment: Hi @ColinTBowers, Sorry I edited it and getting the error above

Comment: I think you think that `Vector{Any}(num_rot1)` creates a vector of length `num_rot1`. It doesn't. As per my comment above, it will throw an error if `num_rot1` is `Int` or `Float64` (this is a deliberate design choice). Just use something like `zeros(Float64, num_rot1)` to initialize a `Vector{Float64}` of length `num_rot1`. Also, I don't know why you're bothering with all the resizing. As near as I can tell, you could remove every `resize!` line and still get the same outcome.